# Checking if the characters in a list of strings is a subset of the characters in another list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given the following lists:

```
list1 = ["Box", "Stall"]
list2 = ["Ball", "Sox"]
```

How can I check whether all the chars that make up 'Ball' and 'Sox', ('BallSox') are contained within 'BoxStall' (the chars that make up 'Box' and 'Stall')? Which they are. It has to be case sensitive.

I tried using the `list()` command within an if statement, checking if all of the chars of the 'Box' are within  `list2`, but it seems like it would have to be a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a built-in function that would handle this.  What you could do is

```
# put all characters of first list into a dictionary 
# object.  This is easier to use for looking up characters
# later
list_chars = {}
for string in list1:
    for char in string:
        list_chars[char] = True


# run through second list, for each character
# in the other list, check if it exists in
# the dictionary of characters from the first 
# list.  If it does not, then set missing_character to True.
missing_character = False
for string in list2:
    for char in string:
        if not list_chars.get(char,False):
            # means that the first list does
            # not contain the character char
            missing_character = True


# print whether one list was actually missing a character.
if missing_character:
   print('Missing some character!')
else
   print('Contained all characters!')
```

Feel free to ask a follow up question if some part of the above doesn't make sense.  Also, you could make the above code a little faster if you use break statements above.  (Exit the for loops early if you already know that the list is missing a character.)  I'll leave that for you to reason through and figure out if you're interested.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain, but I'm not very familiar with Boolean, could you please explain how it is working inside the code
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not being "familiar with Boolean."  I'll try to just explain the code: the first bit creates a dict, list_chars.  A dict has keys and values.  Each key produces a particular value.  Essentially, the first part creates a fast way to check if a character exists in list1.  Like the first part, the second part has two for loops.  The first runs through each string (eg. 'Sox') in list2.  And the second loop runs through each character in that string (eg. 'S', 'o').  The if statement checks whether that char existed in the first list by checking the dict we created.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it like this:

1. Get the list of all unique characters that are in `list2`, lets call this `charlist`
2. Go through `list1`, if any of the characters in the words in `list2` are not in `charlist`, separate them out.

For part 1:

```
>>> charset = set(''.join(i for i in list2))
>>> charset
set(['a', 'B', 'l', 'o', 'S', 'x'])
```

A [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) is a special type that doesn't allow duplicates; every item must be unique.

For part 2:

```
>>> characters_missing = [x for x in ''.join(list1) if x not in charlist]
>>> len(characters_missing)
0
```

Using a [list comprehension](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html) and then calculating the length of the result, we can find out how many letters from `charlist` are not in the words from `list1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the builtin `join` function can allow to have an efficient solution:

```
>>> list1 = ["Box", "Stall"]
>>> list2 = ["Ball", "Sox"]
>>> def chars_subset(l1, l2):
    s1 = "".join(l1)
    s2 = "".join(l2)
    return not bool([c for c in s2 if c not in s1])

>>> chars_subset(list1, list2)
True
>>> list2 = ["Ball", "Soy"]
>>> chars_subset(list1, list2)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The natural way to check whether one set of elements contains elements of another set is to use the built-in `set`.

- First, construct the set of all letters contained in the items of `list1`

  ```
  target = set()
  for item in list1:
      target |= set(item)
  ```

  Note that we're changing our set in place, with the `|=` operator. We could also put the construction of the set in a single line:

  ```
  import operator
  target = reduce(operator.or_, (set(i) for i in list1)
  ```
- Now, we have to iterate on `list2` and check whether the letters of each item are contained in the set:

  ```
  for item in list2:
      if target.issuperset(item):
          print "item {0} passed the test".format(item)
      else:
          print "item {0} failed the test".format(item)
  ```

  You could construct a list of booleans corresponding to this test:

  ```
  valid = [target.superset(i) for i in list2]
  ```

  and check whether all the elements passed the test with `all(valid)`, or if at least one did with `any(valid)`... you get the idea.